# Does pyCUDA works on cloud?

Tags: python, pycuda

I want to use pyCUDA on Microsoft azure. I tried installing it on Google Colab but it is not getting installed. I looked on to the pyCUDA documentation but couldn't find any discussion on it.

Do anyone has any information regarding same?

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-PUtIQA/pycuda/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uDKIjk-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-PUtIQA/pycuda/
```